# Progress dialog not showing

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have two spinners one named cuisine and other area. I m calling the new Thetask().execute on activity load with "init" as argument. And on that the spinners should be set from webservice with the cuisines available and arealist.(methods for that not included here). And initially the spinners will have "All " selected so the listview"restaurantlist" should have all the restaurants. And when the user changes the cuisine or the area from spinners, the restaurantlist listview should be updated with a progressdialog been displayed.
Now My problem is that all the code is working but the progress dialog starts to display after the listview is populated and that progressdialog never stops until back button is pressed.Any solution for this will be a gr8 help.
Thanks in advance.

public class Thetask extends AsyncTask 
     {

```
     String flagdopost="",x,y;       
     @Override 
     public void onPreExecute() 
     {   
        pg =new ProgressDialog(Restaurantlistdisplay.this);
        pg.setMessage("fetching info....");
        pg.setIndeterminate(true);
        pg.setCancelable(true);
        Log.i("inside preexecute","in pre execute");
        pg.show();

     }   

     public Void doInBackground(String... params)
     {          
        if(params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("init"))
        {
            tempcuisinenamelist = getCuisines();    
            tempcuisinenamelist.add(0,"All");

            tempareanamelist=getAreanames(cid, sid, cityid);
            tempareanamelist.add(0,"All");

            flagdopost="init";  
            Log.i("inside doinbackground 1st",flagdopost);
        }

        else if(params[0].equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            firequery();
            flagdopost="itemselected";
            Log.i("inside doinbackground 2nd",flagdopost);
        }
        else if(params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("itemclick"))
        {
            //sendid=getRestaurantId(params[1],params[2]);  
            x=params[1];
            y=params[2];
            Log.i("in do in backgroung idforbundle is", Integer.toString(sendid));
            flagdopost="itemclicked";
        }
        return null;                     
     } 

    public void onPostExecute(Void result)
     {       
        if(flagdopost.equalsIgnoreCase("init"))
        {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptercuisine=new                           ArrayAdapter<String> (Restaurantlistdisplay.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tempcuisinenamelist);
            adaptercuisine.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterarea=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Restaurantlistdisplay.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tempareanamelist);
            adapterarea.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            area.setAdapter(adapterarea); 
            area.setSelection(0);
            area.setOnItemSelectedListener(Restaurantlistdisplay.this);
            cuisine.setAdapter(adaptercuisine); 
            cuisine.setSelection(0);
            cuisine.setOnItemSelectedListener(Restaurantlistdisplay.this);

        }
        else if(flagdopost.equalsIgnoreCase("itemselected"))
        {
            getResult(str);
            customlist.clear();
            populateReslist();
            //Log.i("inside 1st firequery","list populated"+customlist.toString());

            restaurant.invalidateViews();
            restaurant.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(Restaurantlistdisplay.this,customlist,R.layout.customlistrow,new String[] {"Restaurant Name","Area Name"},
                    new int[] {R.id.tvresname,R.id.tvareaname})
                    {
                   @Override      
                   public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
                   {           
                       View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
                       return view;       
                   }  
                 });

         }
        else if(flagdopost.equalsIgnoreCase("itemclicked"))
        {               
            sendid=getRestaurantId(x,y);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("locid",sendid);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "locId in dopost new one"+sendid, 10).show();

            Intent resdetail = new Intent(Restaurantlistdisplay.this,Restaurantdetail.class);
            resdetail.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(resdetail);

        }   
         pg.dismiss();
     }  
 }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) 
{
    switch(arg0.getId())
    {
        case R.id.spncuisine:                                           asynctaskflag="";
                if(cuisine.getSelectedItem().toString()!="All")
                                {
                            cuisineval=cuisine.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        }
                else
                {
                    cuisineval="*";
                }
                new Thetask().execute(asynctaskflag,null,null);
                break;

        case R.id.spnarea:                  
                asynctaskflag="";
                if(area.getSelectedItem().toString()!="All")
                {
                    areaval=area.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }
                else
                {
                    areaval="*";
                }
                new Thetask().execute(asynctaskflag,null,null);
                break;
    }   

}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

//The code of getCuisines() is below as requested by you all. C if that can help

```
public List<String> getCuisines()
 {
        String list = null;
        cuisinelist=new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
       request.addProperty("str", //here goes query to fetch data from table of </br>cuisines);   
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);      
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);     
    aht.debug = true;
    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive results = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        list=results.toString();
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {  
    ex.printStackTrace();
      }
     catch (Exception e)
     {         
    e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
try
{
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(list))); 
    Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("row");
    for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++)
    {
       Node item = items.item(i);
       NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
       for (int j=0;j<properties.getLength();j++)
       {
            Node property = properties.item(j);
        String name = property.getNodeName();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("typeName"))
        {
                   cuisinelist.add(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }                       
        }
    }
    return cuisinelist;         
  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
```

}

Comment: post code for getCuisines() please.

Comment: @Akki posted the code for getcuisines. plz have a look. But buddy i think that when the control goes to itemselected of spinner immediately after population cuisine's spinner the new Task().execute() is run again so may be again progress dialog needs to be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in postexecute

```
 if(pg.isShowing())
{
pg.dismiss();
}
```

and What is getCuisines();? 
do you have any ProgressDialog over there?

if its nested activity then try

```
  ProgressDialog dialogGoog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion will implement it on monday because not cant code at home. Company doesnt allow that. getcuisines is a method that gets the cuisine list of the restaurant. It uses webservice ksoap mthod to get the details and returns an arraylist of cuisines like continental, italian, chinese etc. And the problem as u can c is i populate the adapters and set the adapters so may be the control immediately jumps to onItemselected event of the spinner. And the if pg.isshowing logic that u have suggested might not work but let me give a try. Thanks

Comment: tried it buddy still getting the same kinda output the progress dialog comes after the list view populates. Any further suggestions would be a help ..